# What types of data can be stored in Unity Engine's Vector3 structure?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, data-structures, unity3d-2dtools

I'm a bit new to Unity 2D, so I'm not familiar with what the limitations are of the **Vector3** data structure, but I was wondering if I could store *non-coordinate* and *non-pixel/graphic* related data into it like a regular array.

***Some background info:*** I'm making a 2D dungeon generator and wanted to store coded integers in each index of the main Vector3 array (using two nested for loops), so that the integers could be altered through each iterative pass when generating the dungeon. Then the final layout would take the coded integers and erase the indexed data, and instead instantiate the proper floor or wall tile at that spot.

The codes would be:

- 000 = filled
- 010 = corridor
- 020 = door
- 030 = room
- 100 = protected
- 001 - region 1 [main]
- 002 - region 2
- 003 - region 3,

etc.

So, 32 is a grid piece of type room in region 2. When a corridor connects to it, it becomes 12. When two regions connect from a corridor, it adopts the lower of the two one's place, and so on, until the entire grid is populated with 1's (connected to the main region), at which point they all convert to 0's to indicate that the dungeon is ready for conversion into textures. A 100 is a special flag triggered at x > 99 to signify a block should remain filled, or else accidentally join rooms or expand doorways.

Comment: Er...well, in terms of the exact data you can store in a `Vector3`, that'd be 3 `float` values. Whether or not that suits your requirements is up to how you want to design your program - though I'd probably suggest defining your own class for this with a more descriptive name.

Comment: So am I not able to store, say a string of "pillar" at [3, 2, 5]? Or in the case of Unity 2D, "3, 2, 0f"?

Unity 2D uses integers for Vector3. It accepts floats, but the grid has a static pixel width and height that is set in the Inspector, for which each index is X and Y pixels away from the next. For my nested for loops, I was just going to use integer indices.

Comment: If your requirement is to store 3 related numbers, then a `Vector3` would work for you. If you're trying to associate a `string` with a set of 3 numbers (that you know is unique), then consider a `Dictionary<Vector3, string>`. (And I'm not sure what you mean by `Vector3` using `int` for its coordinates, pretty sure the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) is not ambiguous on `float` being used for them.)

Comment: you can hold transform.position, that's it.  Steven has explained what you want to do otherwise.  do not use it for "other stuff", it's poor engineering

Comment: note too that you are muddled about ints and floats, apart from anything else.  further more you should simply ***learn to use navmesh for the simple problem you are facing***  Unity tutorials are very simple and clear.  save yourself weeks of time.

Comment: I fully understand what an int and float is, but Unity 2D by default uses integer values stored in floats for it's grid. A 2D game with grid-like textures of 16x16 blocks will never use Vector3 values of 3.459, so it's irrelevant to treat them as floats when talking about integer indices. 

Yes, Vector3's use floats, but in Unity 2D, not 3D, Vector3's are not often used as float values except for things like enemies and characters. When laying out a grid-based game background, you set a static width and height for each integer index which matches the width and height of your graphical tiles.

Comment: Furemore, Joe Blow, even though I'm new to video game development, it is my understanding that navmeshes are used for AI character navigation, not level generation. Please don't be rude by ordering me to learn navmeshes and claiming that my problem is clearly simple. Navmeshes most likely cannot work for my purpose, as I intend to randomly populate a map with rooms, corridors, and fills, and then use passes to liken each fill to it's neighbors so that rooms are generated, and likewise for corridors. This technique won't work with navmeshes of any sort. Also, this is a 2D game. Yet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector3 is just 3 floats grouped together labeled x, y, and z.  While you **can** do whatever you want with it, I'd recommend **against** using it for this purpose.  What you want is a custom struct that holds not three ints, but an enum value, an int, and a bool.  like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// A simple struct to represent a tile on the map
/// </summary>
public struct MapTile {
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the tile
    /// </summary>
    public TileType Type;

    /// <summary>
    /// The region this tile is in
    /// </summary>
    public int Region;

    /// <summary>
    /// True if this tile is protected
    /// </summary>
    public bool Protected;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a new MapTile
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The type of the tile</param>
    /// <param name="region">The region the tile is in</param>
    /// <param name="isProtected">true if the tile is protected</param>
    public MapTile(TileType type, int region, bool isProtected) {
        this.Type = type;
        this.Region = region;
        this.Protected = isProtected;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// An enum that contains the types of possible tiles
/// </summary>
public enum TileType {
    FILLED, CORRIDOR, DOOR, ROOM
}
```

It's good practice to make custom structs or classes when the need arises instead of trying to shoehorn your data into existing ones.
Also, trying to store integer values (-1, 2, 7,...) in a float (decimal) is generally a bad idea because floating-point numbers are susceptible to rounding error.  you may want your value to be 25, but the computer may make it 25.00000000001 or 24.9999999999, making it hard to work with.

It's also good practice to avoid "magic numbers", such as how you were planning on storing "corridor" as "010".  If someone saw your code, how would they know that 010 meant corridor? What if you wanted to change it later? Luckily C# (and most other languages) have a built-in type for "number that represents a thing", it's called an enum.  Enums are similar to ints, but they only have the specific values you give them, and are nicely labeled.

I hope this helps!

Comment: That helped a ton, thank you. I've never had any formal programming training, so this is my first introduction to structs and enum values, but this is extremely helpful. 

I just had one more question:

Do these structs allow for something like "xvalue" or "yvalue" to be set in the declaration from a for loop, or should I make a two-dimensional array to store the map grid data?

I had issues earlier in another project where a Class would not allow a variable to be dynamically set and then used when declaring a separate, nested Class. I was wondering if that same issue would arise with this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this.  If you wanted to make one instance of the struct for each spot in a grid, you would need to store them in something like a 2d array.  you could also have the struct store their own coordinates, but that won't help you store or recall the struct later